# Choosing $n$ balls out of $N$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> In a box there are $N$ balls, numbered from $1$ to $N$. Let $n\leq N$ and choose randomly $n$ balls out of $N.$ Let $Y$ denote the largest
>   number on the chosen balls. Find the PMF of $Y.$

I'm having trouble with problems like this. I understand that I'm looking for $P(Y=k)$ if the numbers are $1,2,...,k$ and that we are choosing without replacement and with no regards to order, so we can choose $n$ out of $N$ in a total of ${N\choose n}$ ways.

Now I'm stuck because what if the numbers on the balls start for example with 2 and go to k? Then they are not in order.

Are there any nice and easy way to solve problems like this one?

Comment: One way to approach it:  calculate the probability $P(Y≤k)$.  Note that $P(Y=k)=P(Y≤k)-P(y≤k-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**. Let $B = \{B_1,B_2,\dots B_N\}$ denote then the probability mass function for the random variable $Y$ is given by 
$$\mathbf{P}(Y = k) = \frac{\binom{k-1}{n-1}}{\binom{N}{n}}\text{ }\text{ }\text{for }k\ge n\text{ }\text{ }\text{ and }\mathbf{P}(Y=k) = 0\text{ }\text{ }\text{for }k<n$$

*P.S.* To try see why the above is true,try computing $\mathbf{P}(Y=k),\forall k$ using the above definition for $N=10$ and $n=5$.

---

Answer (score 0):

It does not sound like the numbers have to be in order.

The best way to approach this problem is probably by counting the number of ways $k$ can be largest; you need to pick the ball numbered $k$, and then pick $N-1$ numbers less than k. Can you finish it from here?